# Vim - Uncomment block of code that's using '//' to comment out

Tags: vim

How do you uncomment a block of code that is using '//' to comment out?

I understand using `Ctrl-V` and `x` removes a single row of '/' but how do you do this in one command without repeating this command twice?

Example:

```
//var myAppControllers = angualr.module('myAppCOntrollers',[]);
//
//myAppControllers.controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){ 
//    $http.get('js/data.json).success(function(data){
//        $scope.artists = data;
//        $scope.orderBy = 'name';
//    });
//}]);
```

Comment: When in block selection mode (Ctrl-V), you can modify your selection by using the arrows (or HJKL).

Comment: Repeat is easy with `.` command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is stopping you from using visual block *(Ctrl-V)* mode to remove two rows?  You can select rectangles in visual block mode.  Start at the top left corner of the comment characters, go into visual block mode, and move it to the bottom right of the comment characters.

Answer (score 3):

`Ctrl-V` > `l` > `8j` > `x`

now the explanation:
`Ctrl-V` starts a visual block. One of the main features of Vim that made me fall for it.

`l` does the same as arrow right, namely expand the block to the right. `8j` jumps 8 lines down, so the first 2 columns of 9 lines will be selected. In similar way, you can make the visual block as many columns or lines as you like. You can move around with arrow keys or `hjkl`.

Then just delete them with `x` or `d`

Comment: Depending on your indentation, you may prefer to use `r<space>` instead of `x`/`d`.

Answer (score 2):

What good would be visual-block selection if you couldn't *expand* the selection horizontally?

```
<C-v>ljjjjjjjx
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `s` command.

Select the block you want to uncomment and use `:s/^\/\///`

Comment: this works only for one line. Besides it is much more advanced and without explanation this will only confuse a new vim user.

Comment: vim confuses even experienced users ;) [always funny-learning curves](http://devopsbootcamp.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_images/learning_curves.jpg) ps, if he selected text, it's just a matter of adding "g" to this regex, which besides - is much more than just vim command, and most programmers are fairly familar with it.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are not opposed to plugins, [tpope/vim-commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary) has you covered. Comment and uncomment lines with ease. Even handles nested comments in languages where nested comments are forbidden, like XML.